# Python: How to not print comma in last element in a for loop?

Tags: python, string, list

My code iterates over a set and print actor's names:

```
for actor in actorsByMovies():
    print actor+",",
```

The result looks like:

```
Brad Pitt, George Clooney,
```

But I want it to detect the last element so that it won't print the last comma. The result should be instead:

```
Brad Pitt, George Clooney
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
print(', '.join(actorsByMovies()))
```

Comment: Note that this replaces the entire loop by using Python's built-in `join()` string method to Do The Right Thing.

Comment: Or `print sep+actor, ; sep=', '` with the initial value of `sep` set to the empty string before the loop.

Comment: `join()` has been such a life saver since I found out about it.

Answer (score 6):

The solution by @jamylak is best whenever you can use it, but if you have to keep the loop for other things, you might do something like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function # Python [2.6, 3)

for index, actor in enumerate(actorsByMovies()):
    if index > 0:
        print(', ', end='')
    print(actor, end='')
```

Using the same new `print` function, you could do this instead of using `str.join`:

```
print(*actorsByMovies(), sep=', ')
```

Answer (score 0):

#we can directly use this method in for loop.

```
 x=''
 y=''            #some empty string we want to concatenate(add) the list strings to.
for iterator in list:                #Some list we will be parsing.
     x = x + iterator        # adding value to string available.
     x=x +', '               # adding , and space 
     y= x[:-2]              # as string is immutable adding value of x in y without comma.
   
return y                 # it will return the desired output.
```